# Botão Flutuante Não Fica Por Cima de Textos e Imagems

Tags: html, css

Olá, recentemente fiz um botão flutuante de live-support, ele funciona tudo certo, se move junto com a página e é fixo, porém ele, ao mover junto com a página, vai passando por baixo de textos e imagens, ou seja, ele vai bugando.

Já tentei adicionar no CSS absolute, relative, fixed e nada.

No css está assim:

```
/* livezilla flutuante */
.botaotopo {
  display:scroll;
  position:fixed !important;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  bottom:6px;
  right:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido problema, para quem está com o mesmo problema que eu a solução é fácil:

Apenas adicionar ao CSS:

```
z-index: 9;
```

No caso o número "9" foi usado como referência, mas você pode colocar qualquer número maior que qualquer z-index inserida no CSS.

Comment: Vai chegar um momento na sua vida que irá odiar a propriedade `z-index`, hahaha.

Comment: poderia me dizer por que ? hahaha